# JS pre-fill input fields from URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, events

Im not JS developer, just need it sometimes for very small tasks like this:

I created a form with 3rd party constructor (that is crucial, I must use that constructor) and I want to pre-fill some inputs with data from URL

Example: https://b24-xtskhe.bitrix24.site/?email=test@mail.ru&name=Roman&company=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Pre-fill works, but that form's validator consider fields as empty and you can't send the form before you make any change to that pre-filled inputs

I tried to manually execute some events, none of them helped:
$().change(), .keyup(), .focus(), .trigger('textInput'), .trigger('input')

What is the problem?

My code that pre-fills inputs:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
const queryString = window.location.search;

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

jQuery(".b24-form-field-email").hide();

email = urlParams .get('email');
name = urlParams .get('name');
company = urlParams .get('company');

jQuery("input[name=email]").val(email);

jQuery("input[name=name]").val(name).change();

jQuery(".b24-form-field-string").find('input').first().val(company);});
```

Comment: Which validation library are you using?

Comment: I do not use any, that form built on bitrix24 and it uses it's own validation (if im not mistaken)